# Is there a problem to get a variable by an URL with an url routing in MVC

Tags: php

I can't get the variable in the URL in GET or REQUEST.
If my password is < 6 then return an error. I need to say in my file what is the error by the variable in URL. But i'm stupid, I don't understand why I can't do this...

Model/User.php:

```
public function register() {
    // Sanitize POST
    $post = filter_input_array(INPUT_POST, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);


    if ($post['submit']) {
        $password = $_POST['password'];
        if (strlen($password) < 6) {
            header('Location: '.ROOT_URL. 'users/register?name=12');
            exit(0);
        }


        // Insert into MySQL
        $this->query('INSERT INTO users (name, prenom, sexe, birthday, 
        email, password) VALUES(:name, :prenom, :sexe, :birthday, :email, 
        :password)');
        $this->bind(':name', $post['name']);
        $this->bind(':prenom', $post['prenom']);
        $this->bind(':sexe', $post['sexe']);
        $this->bind(':birthday', $post['birthday']);
        $this->bind(':email', $post['email']);
        $this->bind(':password', $post['password']);
        $this->execute();

        //Verify
        if($this->lastInsertId()) {
            // Redirect
            header('Location: '.ROOT_URL. 'users/login');
        }           
    }
    return;
 }
```

View/register.php:

```
<?php
$timeStamp = date("Y-m-d");

if (isset($_GET['name'])) {
  $model = $_GET['name'];
  echo $model;
} else {
 echo 'not found';
}
?>

    <form method="post" action="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
        <div class="row register-form">
           <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label>Nom</label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" 
                  placeholder="Nom *" required />
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label>Prénom</label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="prenom" 
                placeholder="Prénom *" required />
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label>Sexe : </label> 
                  <label class="radio-inline">
                    <input type="radio" name="sexe" value="Homme">Homme
                  </label>
                  <label class="radio-inline">
                    <input type="radio" name="sexe" value="Femme">Femme
                  </label>
              </div>                    
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
              <div class="form-group">
                <div class="form-group">  
                  <label>E-mail</label>
                  <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" 
                placeholder="E-mail *" required>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label>Mot de Passe</label>
                  <input type="password" name="password" class="form- 
                control" placeholder="Mot de Passe *" required/>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label>Date de naissance : </label>
                  <input type="date" name="birthday" min="1900-00-00" 
                max=" 
                <?php echo $timeStamp ?>">
                </div>

              </div>
              <input type="submit" class="btnRegister" name="submit"  
               value="Inscription"/>
            </div>
        </div>
      </form>
```

Its return a not found in the page.

I need to display an error panel bootstrap in my page for the user understand why the form isn't submit. For the moment i just need to pass a variable in URL for test. All is good, the form, the context of password is good, just the redirection with params in URL isnt good. Why ?

Comment: Are you using a framework? Could we see your form's HTML?

Comment: Not clear what you are asking here. You are passing a query parameter `name` in the redirect and expected it to be empty on the next request? What sense does that make? Also, do you use `$password` or actually `password` like you wrote? Plus, what does `ROOT_URL` contain? Please make sure your question contains all relevant parts.

Comment: I don't use any framework, just PHP in a basic MVC. I post my form html. All is good the submit. 

my ROO_URL is define("ROOT_URL", "http://localhost/helo/");
and my URL final in redirection is http://localhost/helo/users/register?name=12
And sorry I change the goal, and the variables. I try to get the value of name

Comment: @PauloWllier I answered your question yesterday, even with the new code your problem is still the same, your if-else logic is the problem... Have a look at my answer and you will understand the problem... If it is not clear enough leave me a comment ;)

Answer (score 0):

Here is why you are not getting "not found":

As you are passing the parameter `name` you will always get into the

```
if (isset($_GET['name'])) {
    $model = $_GET['name'];
    echo $model;
  }
```

because `isset($_GET['name'])` will always be true...

In order to get in the else statment you should change the logic of your view for something like:

```
if (isset($_GET['name']) && ($_GET['name'] != "error")) {
    //you would get an error bellow if you were using "$GET" intead of "$_GET"...
    $model = $_GET['name'];
    echo $model;
  } else {
    echo 'not found';
}
```

and then change your model to:

```
if ($_POST['submit']) {
    //you would get an error bellow if you were using "password" instead of "$password"
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    if (strlen($password) < 6) {
        header('Location: '.ROOT_URL. 'users/register?name=error');
        exit(0);
    }
}
```

Just for the record, if you are using an MVC framework there are certainly better ways to treat these errors...

Comment: Sorry @Adriano your solution failed :( 
Maybe cause of my controller who give me a state null ?

Comment: @PauloWllier probably not, please do the following...
put the line: `print_r(isset($_GET['name']));` in the first line of your View/register.php and then from your browser access `localhost/helo/users/register?name=12` see what is shown on your screen... it is probably gonna be 1, because `isset($_GET['name'])` will return 1 once you are passing the attribute `name` so it will always get into your `if (isset($_GET['name'])) {
  $model = $_GET['name'];
  echo $model;
}`

Comment: @PauloWllier Basically, you must change your if-else logic inside your View/register.php to get it working in the way you want, my solution is just one example which certainly would work for your case... I just tried it here again to make sure